# How to store variables in a txt file: Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, editing

I have a script with a lot of variables. I was wondering if it was possible to create from the script a txt file and store the variables in it.

notepad.txt

```
Var1: biuhkjlnhi Var 3: kiy8uiojjhu
Var2: ohu89iopkf Var 4: iuyuiojjlou
```

Comment: You probably want [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Marshal.html)

Comment: Or [YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'yaml'

data_before = [var1, var2, var3, var4]
file = '~/foo.yaml'

IO.write file, data_before.to_yaml
data_after = YAML.parse(IO.read(file))

data_before == data_after
=> true # if vars are primitives.
```

Comment: This is probably a stupid question but how do I fix:

undefined method 'to_yaml' for [40, 700, 0.7, 0.3]:Array (NoMethodError)

Comment: you need to 'require "yaml"'

Comment: @zackattack1z1, per @BillDueber I added the necessary `require` statement to the top.

Comment: still getting "undefined method for 'write' for IO:CLASS (NoMethodError)"

Comment: `YAML.parse` isn't working for `Hash` data stored as `yml`. I used `YAML.load` instead. It works like a charme.